# JSF components don't render when using JBoss6 runtime instead of Tomcat7

Tags: jsf-2, jboss6.x

I have a simple form page as shown below:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </h:head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Java Learning Center</h1><hr id="horizontalLine"/>
        <h2><a>Account Login</a></h2>
        <h:outputText value="#{userBean.errorMessage}" style="color:red; text-size:20" />
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText value="Username" />
                <h:inputText value="#{userBean.username}" id="username" required="true" />
                <h:message for="username" style="color:red; text-size:18"/>
                <h:outputText value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret value="#{userBean.password}" id="password" required="true"/>
                <h:message for="password" style="color:red; text-size:18"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{userBean.verifyUser}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</f:view> 
</html>
```

When I am deploying this to Tomcat7 then complete page is displayed. However, when I am deploying the same on JBoss6.1 Runtime, The form elements corresponding to JSF's HTML tag library are not displayed. I'm only seeing content from plain HTML elements like `<h1>` and `<h2>`.

Where am I committing the mistake?

Comment: Replace `<body>` with `<h:body>`, also see the source, see if the `jsf` tags appear in the source html displayed in the browser, if they are displaed it means that `JSF` don't render the file and it's a `web.xml` problem.

Comment: @AVolpe Thanks for pointing out that, but it's still not working

Comment: @AVolpe Got it. The problem was with the "version" attribute of <faces-config> elemnet.

Comment: Add your solution as answers please, it's seems a ver cryptic problem

Comment: @BalusC, but there is no such problem now as the Form page is rendered completely. However, now I am getting some problem with the Bean class.

Comment: @BalusC, and why the JBoss6 Runtime won't render the JSF2.0 components when it internally uses Tomcat as it's Web Server and JBoss also have it's own implementation of JSF2.0 Libraries.

Comment: @AVolpe, Added the solution

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was having problem with my JSF2.0 page not being rendered completely.
However, I came to figure out my *stupidity* in my **config-faces.xml** where i have used:

```
<faces-config
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
   version="1.2">
   ...
</faces-config>
```

instead of :

```
    <faces-config
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
        ...
</faces-config>
```

The kind of problem which arises when using Copy-Paste mechanism without care.